# VB get entire row to two dimentions array

Tags: excel, vba

Im new to VB, and i was told to make a macro in excel, that would go to another excel file, filtre some rows that had specific values in them, and make some % with thoes values, and save the results in another page.

I made a For cycle that i think will solve my problem, but i dont see it working. This is what i have: (i didnt include the part of acessing the other file)

```
Dim exemplo(1, 17) As Integer

        For x = linha_inicial To linha_final
            If Cells(x, 3) = filtro_1 And Cells(x, 4) = filtro_2 Then
                exemplo(exemplo.Length - 1) = Row(x) ' this is if it was 1 dimention array
                exemplo(x) = Row(x)  '? I have no idea what to do here
                ReDim Preserve exemplo(exemplo.Length + 1) ' same applies to here
        Next x
```

Has you can see there, i made the cycle for 1 dimention array, but still i dont understand a few things:
First, if i find the row that has what i want, how do i take the entire row and save it in a two dimentions array (i know the coloms are always 17, so im guessing it would be something like (Row(x),17), but that way it would save the entrie row in the position 17 (ps i also dont know how to get the entire row))

Second, how do i redimention a two dimentions array, from my searches i only found how to do it for a 1 dimention array.

Well i guess that all i need to know for me to understand and finnish my project.
Regardless, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why would you want the entire row, including the huge void part? Anyway

```
a=rows(w).value2
```

but you might want to use:

```
a = Intersect(Rows(w), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Value2
```

to change the size of the LAST dimension, use:

```
Redim preserve a(0 to 3, 0 to 42)
```

for the others, you'll have to copy item by item

Comment: i though that the entire row means the row that is filled :O but thanks for your awnser!

Comment: hm @Pierre , can you explain were the .value2 comes from? is it part of VB ?

Comment: @jeyejow : Its part of VBA, it gives the underlying values of a range. It has some subtle differences with .value

Comment: Much appreciated! @Pierre